# Setting a div with class "row" to display: -webkit-box; makes the contents invisible. Why?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Say you have some HTML like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        Hey there
    </div>
</div>
```

If you do this in your CSS, that content will become invisible, but still take up space in your layout:

```
.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
}
```

Why does that happen and how can it be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

I think -webkit-box has been deprecated: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/

Try using '-webkit-flex' instead.